# I'm receiving an "Uncaught ReferenceError," even though the coding tutorial I was watching step-by-step didn't run into this error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it so when I click the image it adds "points," if you will, to the score.

**My code**

```
<head>
    <title>Axolotl Clicker</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/Warden_Axolotl.png"/>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>

    <img alt="Axolotl in a bucket" src="images/Bucket_of_Blue_Axolotl.png" onclick="addToScore(1)"/>

    <script>
    
        var score = 0;
        
        (function addToScore(amount){
        score = score + amount;
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
        })
        
    </script>

</body>
```

*But*, it says addToScore is undefined, while it's defined just below.

**The error**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addToScore is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onclick (index.html:14:99)  aka: index.html:14

Having no idea what to try, and searching the interweb not helping, I come here to you fine people for your wisdom.

Comment: Please paste your code as text instead of images.

Answer (score 1):

In your `script` tag, your function is wrapped in parentheses. Remove these parentheses and the function should work just fine.
It should look like this:

```
<script>
    var score = 0;
    function addToScore(amount) {
        score = score + amount;
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. you have helped me relieve this headache.